# Native linking failed. Please review the build log in Xamarin.iOS Cross platform

Tags: objective-c, checkbox, xamarin.ios, linker

I am trying to rebuild my xamarin.iOS project in release mode and i am getting following Errors:

1. linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).
2. error MT5209: Error: warning: ignoring file /Users/admin/Desktop/1DMAPP/MobileApp/MobileApp/MobileApp.iOS/obj/iPhone/Release/mtouch-cache/BEMCheckBox.framework/BEMCheckBox, missing required architecture armv7s in file /Users/admin/Desktop/1DMAPP/MobileApp/MobileApp/MobileApp.iOS/obj/iPhone/Release/mtouch-cache/BEMCheckBox.framework/BEMCheckBox (4 slices) (MobileApp.iOS) Native linking
3. /Users/admin/Desktop/1DMAPP/MobileApp/MobileApp/MobileApp.iOS/MTOUCH: Error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: BEMCheckBox. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_BEMCheckBox' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application. (MT5211) (MobileApp.iOS)
4. /Users/admin/Desktop/1DMAPP/MobileApp/MobileApp/MobileApp.iOS/MTOUCH: Error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: BEMCheckBoxGroup. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_BEMCheckBoxGroup' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application. (MT5211) (MobileApp.iOS)
5. /Users/admin/Desktop/1DMAPP/MobileApp/MobileApp/MobileApp.iOS/MTOUCH: Error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log. (MT5202) (MobileApp.iOS)

I am using the latest and stable version of packages.

My Link Behavior is "Don't Link"

My project supports all architectures

I want to build and release my iOS app. Native linking error is not allowing me to do this.

Comment: try to change the behavior and build again,refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/linker?tabs=windows)

Comment: @Leo Zhu - MSFT yes i have tried all the behaviors and the result is same it is not allowing me to build in release mode and still giving me native linking error.

Comment: try :1.Update packages to the latest version 2.Check your csproj files. "<Import Project="..\packages\blah\blah.targets"" -- this should match actual nuget versions. If not -- fix that. 3. Force reinstall all nuget packages. 4.Manually remove bin/obj directories and rebuild